# Remove focus from close button on lightning:overlayLibrary modal

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css, slds, lightning-overlaylibrary

I have a flow modal that is generated via the lightning:overlayLibrary showCustomModal(). Is it possible to remove the default focus (or at least hide the focus with CSS) that is applied to the close button on these modals?

[image: screenshot]

Code that creates the modal:

```
 $A.createComponents([
        ['c:gFlowContainer', flowParameters],
        ['c:gModalOverlayHeader', {title: component.get('v.modalSettings').title}],
    ],
    function(components, status) {
        if (status === 'SUCCESS') {
            modalBody = components[0];
            modalHeader = components[1];
            component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal({
                header: modalHeader,
                body: modalBody,
                showCloseButton: typeof component.get('v.modalSettings').showCloseButton !== 'undefined' ? component.get('v.modalSettings').showCloseButton : true,
                cssClass: component.get('v.modalSettings').cssStyling,
                closeCallback: function() {
                    // let our parents know to do any afterAction tasks
                    component.getEvent('afterAction').fire();
                },
            }).then(function(overlay) {
                // unused at the moment
            });
        }
    });
```

Playing around with styling the close button (have been unsuccessful to "style away" the focus outline:

```
<aura:component >    
<lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib"/>

<!-- Parameters -->
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" description="Record Id"/>
<aura:attribute name="name" type="String" default="needsaname" description="The string to use as a name of the modal" />
<aura:attribute name="modalSettings" type="Object" default="{ title: 'Specify Title' }" description="This object holds modal settings" />
<aura:attribute name="flowSettings" type="Object" default="" description="This object holds flow settings" />
<aura:attribute name="lightningSettings" type="Object" default="" description="This object holds lightning component settings" />

<!-- Methods -->
<aura:method name="showModal" action="{! c.handleShowModal }" access="PUBLIC"/>
<aura:method name="showModalWithParams" action="{! c.handleShowModalWithParams }" access="PUBLIC">
    <aura:attribute name="actionDefinition" type="List" description="The action definition"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="recordIdIn" type="Id" description="The recordId to be used."/> 
</aura:method>

<!-- Events Fired -->
<aura:registerEvent name="afterAction" type="c:evtClick" description="Event fired when an action is complete"/>

<aura:html tag="style">
.slds-modal__close {
    color:#2ecc71;
}

</aura:html>
```

</aura:component>

Answer (score 1):

Was able to remove the styling by adding this to my component markup:

```
<aura:html tag="style">
.slds-modal__close:focus {
    color: var(--slds-c-button-brand-text-color, 
        var(--sds-c-button-brand-text-color, 
        var(--lwc-colorTextBrandPrimary,rgb(255, 255, 255)))); 
        border: 0px; 
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
}
</aura:html>
```